# Bar chart working in localhost but not working after hosting on gitpage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, networking, github-pages

[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JtoI.png)

[Gitpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIjXY.png)

The bar chart is working fine in localhost but after hosting on gitpage it's not showing properly. What to do?

Repo: https://github.com/mzs21/bar-chart

Live: https://mzs21.github.io/bar-chart/

Answer (score 0):

The JS appears to be working ok and the app is running OK but I think the CSS is missing, so I completely understand your confusion!

You're using Tailwind so I'm going to assume that the Git pages deploy does not trigger the Tailwind build process. As that's done transparently locally you would not be 'hosting' the CSS that you would see.

I know posting links is naughty but as you're new have a read of this blog: https://harrywang.medium.com/introducing-tailpages-tailwind-github-pages-89903c52d3ec

Comment: I've used Tailwind CSS properly in my other projects but this is the 1st time I'm facing this issue. Thanks for showing the Talipages but I want to stick with what I have done & fix this.